# How do I setup AWS Kinesis Data Stream which gets data from an existing API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-agent

I currently have a GET API endpoint which gives me realtime data of an object. I want to set up AWS Kinesis Data Stream such that it requests data from the API every 5 seconds and directs the output to AWS RDS. How do I get kinesis to query the API every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get kinesis to query the API every 5 seconds?

You can't as kinesis does not have such functionality. You have to implement it yourself. For example, a lambda function that queries your endpoint every 5 seconds and injects records to the stream.